# Animal companion Final Embrace feat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, animal-companions

Can an animal companion (Constrictor Snake) once it reaches 3 INT acquire the [Final Embrace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/final-embrace-combat/) feats? I found no other way of getting Final Embrace without being a Naga or serpent-folk.

Answer (score 6):

### Yes.

> Prerequisites: Str 13, Int 3; naga, serpentfolk, or creature that has the constrict special attack as a racial ability; base attack bonus +3.

You have four requirements to qualify for [Final Embrace](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#final-embrace):

- Str 13;
- Int 3;
- Be a [naga](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/naga/), [serpentfolk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/monstrous-humanoids/serpentfolk/), or a creature that has the constrict special attack as a racial ability; *You only need to meet one of these requirements here, not all three*.
- Base attack bonus +3.

Looking up the animal companion sheet for [Constrictor Snakes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Snake-Constrictor), we see that they gain *constrict* at 4th level:

> **Snake, Constrictor**
>
> Starting Statistics
>
> Size Medium; Speed 20 ft., climb 20 ft., swim 20 ft.; AC +2 natural armor; Attack bite (1d3 plus grab); Ability Scores Str 15, Dex 17, Con 13, Int 1, Wis 12, Cha 2; Special Qualities low-light vision, scent.
>
> 4th-Level Advancement
>
> Size Large; AC +1 natural armor; Attack bite (1d4); Ability Scores Str +8, Dex –2, Con +4; **Special Attacks constrict 1d4**.

That means that a constrictor snake animal companion, from a character that has an *effective druid level* of at least 4th level, should qualify for [Final Embrace](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCombat/ultimateCombatFeats.html#final-embrace).

One could argue about the **racial** requirement, but the fact that the creature gains the ability from no external sources (like being an animal companion or gained from a feat), except for the fact that it is a constrictor snake ([bestiary entry](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/snake/snake-constrictor/)), means that the ability is a [racial ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/#TOC-Racial-Bonus).

> A racial bonus comes from the culture a particular creature was brought up in or because of **innate characteristics of that type of creature**.

Looking at the feat's requirements again:

> Prerequisites: Str 13, **Int 3;**

There would be *no reason* to list a requirement of **Int 3** if the point wasnt to [allow animal companions to qualify for the feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/animal-companions/#TOC-Feats). There have been no known cases of feats that have a minimum *Int* requirement that is that low for player characters, normally you must have a higher than average int score ([like 13](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/combat-expertise-combat/)), or no minimum intelligence is required at all to qualify and use the feat.

Comment: You list all of the reasons that the answer is yes, but you never explicitly say that it is. For clarity, explicitly say "Yes, you can."

Comment: *That means that a constrictor snake animal companion, from a character that has an effective druid level of at least 4th level, should qualify for Final Embrace.* I thought this was clear enough.